# Render external page content via REST call

Tags: mediawiki, mirror, restful

Does anyone know of any extensions or ways to be able to grab content from a REST call and render it in a MediaWiki page?

Long story short I need to maintain access to a legacy MediaWiki installation but all new content will be on a Confluence server. I want to just be able to pull content from each Confluence page into the corresponding MediaWiki page with a REST call.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you want to turn the MediaWiki wiki into a live mirror of the Confluence wiki. Correct? Sounds like a nightmare. :)

The opposite, i.e. a live mirror of MediaWiki wikis, is rather easy: you just call `action=render` on the desired page ([example](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext?action=render)) or use the appropriate [parsing API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) to get the HTML. The MediaWiki URLs can be made RESTful with [`$wgActionPaths`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgActionPaths). This is the strategy used for instance by the Wordpress plugin [Wiki Embed](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wiki-embed/).

Confluence is not that easy to use and its web APIs look quite limited, but you can [attempt fetching the HTML of a page](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/19136565/answers/19136642). Embedding HTML on individual MediaWiki pages is feasible e.g. with [$wgRawHtml](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml) (I suppose editing rights are restricted on this wiki). You will need to do this manually for each page because Confluence doesn't have [free linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_link) and you won't have an automatic way to map titles to URLs.